# Jquery-ui draggable not working after appendchild()

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm developing a website that has a canvas and a tool box. In the tool box there are buttons to add to canvas the chosen tool (I made this way because I was not able to implement a working drag and drop). The point is exactly this, when I press the button of the tool, this tool will appear in canvas as a `draggable` element. But It simple doesn't work, I can make the tool appear, but It stay fixed(not able to drag It on the canvas)

My button code:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="addToCanvas();"> 
  <img id="computer" src="images/myImage.png" width="40px;" height="40px;">
</button>
```

My javascript function for "addToCanvas()"

```
function addToCanvas(number){
var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = '<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><img  src="images/myImage.png" width="60px;" height="60px;"></div>';
wrapper.setAttribute('id',"draggable");
wrapper.setAttribute('class',"ui-widget-content");
canvas.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

Do you guys have any idea what It could be? Thanks

Comment: Try putting it in a fiddle, it will encourage people to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating it with the id of `draggable`, but that alone doesn't make it *actually* draggable.  You need to call the jQuery function on the object, once it has been added to the DOM.

```
function addToCanvas(number){
   var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
   wrapper.innerHTML = '<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><img  src="images/myImage.png" width="60px;" height="60px;"></div>';

   // it appears to me these next two lines are redundant - you're already seeting their values in the innerHTML
   wrapper.setAttribute('id',"draggable");
   wrapper.setAttribute('class',"ui-widget-content");

   canvas.appendChild(wrapper);
   $('#draggable').draggable();   // <-- this is the missing piece
}
```

From the Draggable API found [here](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Also, you have a mixture of plain javascript and jQuery UI in there - I would keep it simple and just go jQuery all the way and make my function look like this:  (I removed the number parameter since you weren't using it for anything, or even passing it in on click event)

```
function addToCanvas() {

   var $draggable = $('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><img  src="images/myImage.png" width="60px;" height="60px;"></div>');
   canvas.append($draggable);
   $draggable.draggable();

}
```

Sample JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7wechzp6/2/).

Comment: Hey Danny, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked. :/ My script file already have the  $('#draggable').draggable();

The second solution proposed don't add the the tool to canvas (the image dont appear) :/

Comment: I left out the wrapping $() around the html in $draggable - sorry about that. Fixed it now.  Added a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Danny the second solution gives me an error: canvas.append is not a function.

Comment: You never said was `canvas` was, but since you were using jQueryUI I was assuming it was jQuery element, like in my fiddle.

Comment: Sorry man, my bad, I'm new to front-end development. My canvas is: 
<div>
        <section id="canvas">
        <section>
<div>

I tried to put the id on the <div> as you did, but I still get the error. I saw you Fiddle, It is exactly what I want to do. your fiddle works great!

Comment: No worries - that's why you're here, right?  I updated my JSFiddle link so that `canvas` is a section just like you wrote, and it still works. Are you perhaps not wrapping it as a jQuery element, and are just using it as a JavaScript object from getElementById?  Check out the link in my fiddle that declares canvas: `var canvas = $('#canvas');` and see if that's the problem.

Comment: Danny, SORRY , NOW IT WORKED!!!!! I didn't notice the line: var canvas = $('#canvas'); in your Fiddle Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked.  As long as you're using jQuery then I would just always use that and forget getElementById even exists.  :)

Comment: Ok, I will do that! I still have to study Jquery too. Thank you so much, man, you Rock!